# How can "sbt runAll" command stay alive?

Tags: docker, sbt, lagom

How can "sbt runAll" command stay alive? Does "sbt runAll" command have parameters for it to stay alive?

I created a Logam sample file and then a docker image by installing Java v8 and sbt v1.2.1. My Dockerfile is at the end of my question.

When I run docker command 
    "docker run -p 57798:57797 -d lagom-hello-world",

sbt command goes through its initiating process and everything appears ok. However, sbt command ends itself as soon as it completes the initiation process. How can "sbt runAll" command stay alive?

## Contents in My Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8

RUN \
  curl -L -o sbt-1.2.1.deb http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian/sbt-1.2.1.deb && \
  dpkg -i sbt-1.2.1.deb && \
  rm sbt-1.2.1.deb && \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install sbt && \
  sbt sbtVersion

EXPOSE 57797

WORKDIR /app

ADD . /app

CMD sbt runAll
```

Comment: looks like you want to run multiple applications (multi-module sbt project) inside the single docker container which would defeats the purpose of docker. try docker compose or package the project using `sbt package` command and run every single project using `java -jar command` in custom shell script

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to want to do this. Each of your services should be contained it in its own image and you'll run those images individually, coordinating with k8s or marathon or similar.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. I have a single application. For now, just hello world. I need the "sbt runAll" (or "sbt run") process staying up. Currently, it's shut down automatically after initiation.

Comment: @LeeZ You can use [this](https://github.com/erip/ticketing-service/blob/master/bin/run_main_sbt.sh), which is a script I've written to do effectively the same thing.